# How does Rails find the correct database adapter through the database.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

The database.yml file has a `adapter: postgresql`, how does this lead the rails server to connect to the postgres program? If I'm running the server locally does Rails look through my `PATH` or something to find the location of where my postgres is installed?

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't have to know where it's installed. It connects to a running service called postgres which runs on localhost port 5432 unless you change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

databases are client-server software. So your rails app connects to the database server via hostname/IP address, port number and db credentials (username/password) which can exist anywhere on the network.

If you are developing a rails application on your localhost and have the database binaries installed on the same machine you are developing. Then, in order to connect to that db server, you must have a database daemon running on your localhost listening to a port (deafault port is `5432` for postgresql). You can test status of your postgres daemon using `netstat -an | grep 5432`

you can change the port number on your app's `config/database.yml` if you are using a different one (if you do not specify port number and using postgresql adaptor, it assumes the default port number `5432`)

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_dev
  username: dev_user
  password: dev_pass
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

Comment: thanks @sa77!  it seems like there is a client-server relationship between the rails server and database, with rails being the client pinging the db server for stuff. in order for them to connect, they go through port 5432. when a user starts postgres, it defaults to make a program (daemon) whose responsible for listening on port 5432 for other programs who want to interact with it. In that sense the daemon is like an API. in rails' `database.yml` it will connect to any db on port 5432, so that's how it goes through that port on the users machine and hits up the daemon to get to postgres?

Comment: yes .. the daemon is your postgres server running on the background which listens to port `5432` for any API request to the tables on your database. The database name, port number, database username and password configuration on your `database.yml` file defines your rails application's ORM library (ActiveRecord::Base) about which database to access for the data in your application .. you can check the details about db connection between your rails application and postgres with this `ActiveRecrod::Base.connection` from your `rails console`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty much right in the `database.yml` comments:

```
 # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432. 
 # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly. 
 # port: 5432
```

So, if you've done a vanilla installation, then rails just uses port 5432 to connect to your and communicate with your database.

Comment: so rails uses port 5432 to listen and postgres by default is automatically set to connect to anything listening on port 5432, so that's how they connect?

Comment: When you install PGSQL, the default port is 5432, unless that is already in use. Unless you are running on port 5432 - yes - you need to specify it in database.yml as @jvillian has mentioned.